# World-wide web or perhaps a bit more narrow-minded?

Tags: riddle, visual, computer-puzzle

## Beware: solving this riddle requires being technically fluent in both digital platforms described below (using them both is essential).

Even though [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) doesn't propagate itself as being narrow-minded; when integrated into [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/), ... it shows its true colors.

**Typo**

> ... it shows its three colors.

**Typo** (Again, sorry; I'm starting to use AZERTY, about which you can find out more on Wikipedia. It's ok to feel blue for me, since not many people use this.):

> ... it shows its tricolor.

**Hint**

> Node: a central or connecting point.

A nice screen-grabber might facilitate an explanatory visual answer of minimum 200 pixels wide & 35 pixels high.

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: @Agawa001 I added a warning. Solving this riddle requires some technicalities.

Comment: The tag #visual didn't seem appropriate, if I'm wrong please re-add it.

Comment: Is this actually a puzzle, or are you just upset that Bootstrap integration with Drupal is very limited?

Comment: @ leoll2 It isn't always as it seems; but in this case, it is very focused on the seeming. I re-added the tag **visual**.

@IanMacDonald I have had *almost* no problems with limitations. You might be on the right track to solve compatibility issues, but not to solve my riddle. Funny comment though!

Comment: Lovely obscure puzzle, I'm curious to see the solution. (I'm not eligible as a puzzle-solver for this one...)

Comment: Should I upload the answer myself, since not many people seem to be eligible to? The answer is very obvious.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: @Bret The question was asking for an adept visual answer which would explain the riddle (cf. the last hint of the question); as started with the question in the title.

Comment: This question appears messy — and is, somewhat, — but under all that, it isn't all too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer (the French national flag included in [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) on [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/))

... Since not too many people seemed to be using the [Bootstrap-module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) of [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) here: ...

The "true colors" / "3 colors" / "[tricolor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricolour_%28flag%29)", was trying to refer to a flag with 3 colors; which is also sometimes referred to as a [triband](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triband_%28flag%29). The references to a nationality were also in the "being more narrow-minded" than the "world-wide web".

The hint about a **node**, as "connecting the dots" *of the riddle*; referred to the editing of any **node** in Drupal (± a technical Drupal-term for **article**); which would have the shown the following composition (which has the minimum dimensions of ± 200 *X* 30 pixels):

[image: French flag in Drupal's Bootstrap-module]

This is exactly the French flag:

[image]

Notice also the reference to the [Wikipedia page of AZERTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY), which is mainly used in French-speaking countries. The country coloured **blue** (cf. OP) on the main image of that Wikipedia-entry is France:

[image]

Comment: Well, this was very very technical. Currently, Puzzling doesn't have enough people to grant a decent amount of users skilled in Bootstrap and Drupal. This means, just few people (if none) could make progress solving this puzzle.

Comment: I would be careful about how you word answers like this in the future. I disagree that true colors / tricolor _obviously_ refers to a flag.

Comment: I seem to agree that little users here used the [Bootstrap-model](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap), which is why I revealed the answer. | @Bailey You make a good point. It seems that even the Wikipedia-entry for [Tricolor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricolor), lists other items such as animal coats, a river & sport teams; amongst many entries for flags though. But I agree with your adept comment & will fine-tune the answer.

Comment: One could call your usage of "tricolor" narrow-minded ... ;)

Comment: @IanMacDonald Good catch! According to Wikipedia, the [Flag of France](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_France) is known to English speakers as the "**Tricolour**" *(French: "Tricolore")*; but the world-wide web is wider indeed then this single use. :) You are correct about my limitations.